# Drobo redundancy

Tags: drobo, redundancy, windows-home-server

Given the inexplicable demise of Drive Extender technology in Windows Home Server, I am considering other options, such as replacing it with [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com) (and a linux server).

One thing I'm not 100% clear on is the unit of redundancy in a Drobo. In WHS, I can set a specific folder as requiring redundancy and let other folders "live on the edge" without any redundancy. From what I can tell, it sounds as though with Drobo it's an all or nothing affair. I can specify that I want to be able to recover from a single HDD failure (or maybe even two) but I can't say "don't worry about creating redundant copies of these files".

Am I right in my understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right. Effectively, the capacity of the largest disk in the Drobo is lost for redundancy. During regular use, you can think of it as a RAID 5 system with some flexibility regarding extensibility and drive sizes.

Screenshot of my Drobo Dashboard:
[image]

The *overhead* is negligible, and *used for protection* (1.83 Tebibytes) is exactly the size of one of the largest HDDs (2 Terabytes).

(Note that the "maximum capacity" of the volumes is only a virtual value I configured -- I don't know what happens when the Drobo fills up but the volumes tell my system there's space left for use)

Comment: My understanding of how Drobo works when it gets near to 100% full is that it slows down I/O exponentially to give you enough time to insert a new drive in the array.